# C++ Pointer to Object as Class member

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to get two different classes to interact with eachother, for that I have in one class a pointer to an object of an other class, which is specified in the constructor.
Interaction works so far, I can change the paramters of the pointed-to object and I can see the changes, as I'm printing it on a terminal. BUT when I try to get a parameter from this object and try to print it to the terminal through the class which points to it I only get a zero value for an Int from which I know, cause of debug outputs, that it isn't zero, if called directly.
I will give you an example of the code:

### **Class A:**

```
class Spieler
{
    private:
        int score;
        Schlaeger *schlaeger;
        int adc_wert;
        int channel;


    public:

        Spieler(int x, Schlaeger &schl, int adc_wert_c=0, int channel_c=0 )
        {
            score=x;
            schlaeger=&schl;
            adc_wert=adc_wert_c;
            channel=channel_c;
        }
    //....
        void set_schl(Schlaeger &schl){ schlaeger=&schl;}
        int getPosY(){ schlaeger->getSchlaeger_pos_y();}
        int getPosX(){ schlaeger->getSchlaeger_pos_x();}
        void setPosY(int y){ schlaeger->set_pos_y(y);}      

        void schlaeger_zeichen(){
            schlaeger->schlaeger_zeichen();
        }

        void schlaeger_bewegen(){
            schlaeger->schlaeger_bewegen(getADC());
        }
//...

};
```

### Class B:

```
class Schlaeger
{
    private:
        int schlaeger_pos_x;
        int schlaeger_hoehe;
        int schlaeger_pos_y;
    public:

        Schlaeger(int x=0, int h=5, int pos_y=15)
        {
            schlaeger_pos_x=x;
            schlaeger_hoehe=h;
            schlaeger_pos_y=pos_y;
        }

        int getSchlaeger_pos_x()
        {
            return schlaeger_pos_x;
        }
        int getSchlaeger_pos_y()
        {
            return schlaeger_pos_y;
        }
        int getSchlaeger_hoehe()
        {
            return schlaeger_hoehe;
        }
        void set_pos_y(int new_y)
        {
            schlaeger_pos_y=new_y;
        }


};
```

The calls to the changing methods work, I can see the changes and I can see it in a debug output.

Comment: Could you clear up your question? it's very confusing.

Comment: Please simplify your code to show only what is necessary to reproduce the problem you are having. Also, what is the output you get and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: `getSchlaeger_pos_y` is a really weird name. What is it supposed to do, actually? It seems like you're having some problems with OOP in general.

Comment: how could `int getPosY(){schlaeger->getSchlaeger_pos_y();}` work ??
I think it should give you a compilation error, their is no return value !! please simplify your code and make your question more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning the value in the getter

```
int getPosY(){ schlaeger->getSchlaeger_pos_y();}
```

should be

```
int getPosY(){ return schlaeger->getSchlaeger_pos_y();}
```

Comment: OMG, I just have overlooked this -.- Thank you VERY MUCH!

Comment: @Kelevra Turn up the warning level of your compiler. This code should produce a warning.

Comment: @pmr Why exactly? And I will see where I can set the warning level.

Comment: @Kelevra The warning is because you're saying that the method returns a value, and is not returning anything.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just thought that he maybe meant something else apart from these two missing return statements.